# PyQt5 with Qtablewidget program crashes without any exception

Tags: python, pyqt5

I use tablewidget in my `PyQt5` code and add some widgets into the cells with `setCellWidget` method.

Each time I tried to type in some Chinese characters, the program crashes, which goes fine when I type in English.

I use `python 3.7.2`, and tried every version of `PyQt5` from `5.9.0` to `5.12`.

I shrink my code into the following sample. Whenever I add a widget, combobox, lineedit whatever, it crashes when I type in.

So my question is why is this happening?

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
table = QTableWidget()
table.setRowCount(2)
table.setColumnCount(4)
table.setCellWidget(0, 1, QComboBox())
table.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you clarify: a) OS and version, b) the way you run your program, c) if you run it from command line - do you see messages in `bash`/`sh`/`cmd`/`powershell` window?

Comment: I tried your code and it ran without error (on OSX 10.14). I even copy-pasted some Chinese characters from the Wikipedia. Can you add a line to your example that adds the characters programmatically? This way we can try to reproduce the issue better.

Comment: Thanks for help! I run the program from command line on windows7, and there is nothing pop up on the command line when program crashes.

Comment: I did't find a good way to reproduce it programmatically because the problem doesn't show up when I paste the character or edit it programmatically, only when I type in. I override the keyPressEvent and itemchanged event, neither of them showed anything before the program crashes. I even tried different input method programs and on different machines with Windows10. Nothing works!